# SQL Server database count with extra information

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get a count of all table's row count along with min (record with min date like 27 jan 2010) and max (max date record in that table like 27 jan 2014). Can someone help how can it be done?

The purpose is to save time running queries like

```
select min(datetime) from t1
```

and

```
select max(datetime) from t1.
```

Your help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: Lookup sp_MSForEachTable

Answer (score 0):

This query will help you to get the Table Name and their row count

```
SELECT sc.name +'.'+ ta.name TableName
 ,SUM(pa.rows) RowCnt
 FROM sys.tables ta
 INNER JOIN sys.partitions pa
 ON pa.OBJECT_ID = ta.OBJECT_ID
 INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc
 ON ta.schema_id = sc.schema_id
 WHERE ta.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND pa.index_id IN (1,0)
 GROUP BY sc.name,ta.name
 ORDER BY SUM(pa.rows) DESC
```

[Refer more here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2537/sql-server-row-count-for-all-tables-in-a-database/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all with 1 query

```
select count(*), min(someDate), max(someDate) from someTable;
```